# Broken libperl5 package when trying to install updates

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.10

Starting today, I cannot do any updates on my Ubuntu 16.10 desktop computer.  When I try to run commands such as `sudo apt-get update` it says:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsnmp30:i386 : Depends: libperl5.22:i386 (>= 5.22.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I try to run `sudo apt-get install -f`, it says:

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 libperl5.22 i386 5.22.2-3 [3,028 kB]
Fetched 3,028 kB in 0s (34.5 MB/s)         
(Reading database ... 336306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libperl5.22_5.22.2-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libperl5.22:i386 (5.22.2-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.22_5.22.2-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libperl5.22/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libperl5.22:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.22_5.22.2-3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone know the trick to fix this?  I don't know why I would have a i386 package, since this is a 64-bit installation:

```
Linux loup 4.8.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 21 17:24:18 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Comment #3 from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/+bug/1574351 had this workaround which worked perfectly for me:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/doc/libperl5.22/changelog.Debian.gz
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Thanks, Reuben Firmin, whoever you are!